# PDF from CDF in Python

Tags: python, cdf

Does anybody know if there is a tool to compute PDF from CDF in Python on arbitrary grid and for CDF of arbitrary number of variables.

PDF - probability distribution function
CDF - cumulative distribution function

Comment: There's probably some obscure Scipy route, but I have no idea what it would be.

Comment: The PDF is the derivative of the CDF curve. Use any tool that calculates derivatives or write a one line solution yourself.

Comment: My understanding PDF is mixed martial derivative of CDF. If we have 5 variables, the numerical error in differentiation is going to be overwhelming. am I missing something? The only solution I see is through computing differences in appropriate areas. It is easy to visualize in 2 and 3 dimensions, but in higher dimensions it is a bit difficult to generalize.